# How to consolidate arrays into 1

Tags: array, js

Ive been working on consolidating large amounts of data and i have gotten the array to this point.

[{"StockKeepingUnit":"SU-002","Description":"01t2z000001vAasAAE","2022-09-07":5},
{"StockKeepingUnit":"SU-002","Description":"01t2z000001vAasAAE","2022-09-20":7},
{"StockKeepingUnit":"SU-002","Description":"01t2z000001vAasAAE","2022-09-23":1}]

but i would like the result to be like this

[{"StockKeepingUnit":"SU-002","Description":"01t2z000001vAasAAE","2022-09-07":5,"2022-09-20":7,"2022-09-23":1}]

So merging into 1 and deleting the duplicate values. The result will then go into a data table.

Help greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to merge by SKU, that would look like this:

```
const productsBySku = {};
// For each line item
source.forEach((item) => {
  // Get existing match or initialize a new object
  const product = productsBySku[item.StockKeepingUnit] || {};
  // Copy the values from the lineitem to the object
  Object.assign(product, item);
  // Store this object by SKU
  productsBySku[item.StockKeepingUnit] = product;
});
// Convert the object back to an Array
const products = Object.values(productsBySku);
```

If you have multiple SKUs, you can also use the reduce function:

```
const result = source.reduce(
  (p, v) => (
    (p[v.StockKeepingUnit] = { ...(p[v.StockKeepingUnit] || {}), ...v }), p
  ),
  {}
);
```

If you want the same type of Array back, just add Object.values() as before:

```
const result = Object.values(
  source.reduce(
    (p, v) => (
      (p[v.StockKeepingUnit] = { ...(p[v.StockKeepingUnit] || {}), ...v }), p
    ),
    {}
  )
);
```

This returns the same type of output as the first example, in bulk, per SKU.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. So before this code I used:
        const result = this.obj.filter(
          (word) => word.StockKeepingUnit == "SU-002"
        );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

to get only Su-002 items, but Im gonna need too do this to multiple items. How would i bulkify this code?

Comment: @knay If you have that, you can also: `source.reduce((p,v)=>{...p,...v},{})`, which will return the single consolidated object. My example assumed that there were multiple SKUs involved.

Comment: @knay Also, I'll edit in an alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't wait til im as good at this as you